# Repository in Spring REST Application

Tags: rest

I have a simple question which I can't find an answer for when I google it: when building a spring REST web application is it alright for repositories to be annotated with @Repository as in: @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String>, or should this annotation not be used in REST applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, repository should be annotated as `@Repository`. I'm using it and it works :D
My example:

```java
@Repository
public interface RepositoryNote extends JpaRepository<EntityNote, UUID> {

    EntityNote findByUuid(UUID uuid);
}
```

Documentation about `@Repository`:

```
Indicates that an annotated class is a "Repository", originally defined by
  Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "a mechanism for encapsulating storage,
  retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a collection of objects".
```